# wordpress auto newsletter plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have a Wordpress website with a custom theme which includes Galleries, Testimonies and others.
I'm looking for a plugin that would automatically send an updated email to my subscribers every time something new is added. It should be something very simple to handle. For example the plugin would use a custom template that needs to be created (using the same shortcodes and style-sheet as the website theme). Then it would detect the website sections such as Posts, Galleries, Testimonies, etc and using check-boxes I could select which one I want to include in the newsletter. It would be so convenient for me and the newsletter would be taken care of by Wordpress itself.
Does this kind of plugin exist?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-automatic-newsletter/

Comment: Thanks it's a good one, just lacks of customization. So I found this one: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wysija-newsletters/